# Embedding a Python web-based shell (Werkzeug?)

Tags: python, django, werkzeug

I'm looking for a way to embed a python interpreter in a web page. Specifically, something similar to a textarea/REPL having access to the scope of a Django template.

[Werkzeug](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/) Does something similar, but I'm unable to find any example or documentation regarding the embedding process. Help is very welcome!