# Python/Django generate runtime exception

Tags: python, django, werkzeug

I'm using werkzeug in a Django project using Apache/mod_wsgi. What I want to do is access the werkzeug python shell without there actually being an error. The only way I can figure to do this is to intentionally cause an error when the url pattern `url(r'^admin/shell', forceAnError())` is matched.

Admittedly, intentionally causing an error isn't the optimal course of action, so if there's a way to simply call/import/render/access the werkzeug python shell from a template or something, that would be the better solution.

Comment: I hint you to look into the template used by werkzeug when an error occours

Comment: I'm pretty much a Python noob, but I'll see if I can find it.

Comment: obviously there are some security problems if you make this URL accessible from anyone, I advice you to limit the access to the superuser only or by IP

Comment: Yeah, it's definitely not going to be present in production, and even in prototyping I'm looking into restricting access.

Comment: I have located the code that appears to drive the console, located at `werkzeug/debug/` But I'm not sure how to implement this in django.

Comment: I also just noticed that [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15052818/can-i-call-the-werkzeug-debugger-in-django-without-needing-to-raise-an-exception) and [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15029729/embedding-a-python-web-based-shell-werkzeug) are asking essentially the same thing I am.

Answer (score 0):

If you wrap your WSGI application in a `werkzeug.debug.DebuggedApplication` with `evalex` on, you'll get a shell available at `/console`:

```
from werkzeug.wrappers import Request, Response
from werkzeug.debug import DebuggedApplication

@Request.application
def app(request):
    return Response("Normal application, nothing to see here...")

app = DebuggedApplication(app, evalex=True)
# console_path is another optional keyword argument.
# you can guess what it does.
```

[image: The Werkzeug console runs.]

Comment: I didn't realize it was that simple, I even already had `evalex=True`. Oddly enough, the people on the #pocoo IRC told me that doing such a thing wasn't possible... Apparently they had no idea what they were talking about.

Comment: @TNels: I just looked at the source code and saw `console_path` and thought: oh, hey, what's this? I tried it and it's exactly what you wanted.